# Настройка отладчика в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Я не использую STL, вместо этого использую свои собственные велосипедные классы строк и динамических массивов. Проблема в том, что строки у меня не нуль-терминированные, поэтому отладчик отображает мусор в конце строки. А указатель на элементы внутри массива имеет тип `void*`, из-за чего отладчик вообще не показывает его элементы.

Как научить Visual Studio 2013 понимать мои классы в таком виде, в каком они есть? Пробовал написать .natvis файл, но похоже, что там даже нет возможности задать размер строки, и он считает строки ограниченными нулём, потому и выводит тот же мусор в конце. А для массивов непонятно, как получить тип T его элементов, чтобы привести указатели типа `void*` в указатели типа `T*` и их уже отображать как массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось!
 Со строками надо было так сделать:

```
<DisplayString>{start,[end-start]}</DisplayString>
```

А с массивами надо было просто в класс добавить что-то вроде `typedef T ET`, и этот ET уже можно использовать в выражениях:

```
<ArrayItems>
    <Size>(ET*)data.End-(ET*)data.First</Size>
    <ValuePointer>(ET*)data.First</ValuePointer>
</ArrayItems>
```